# Set the background for ImGui::BeginGroup() using C++

Tags: c++, imgui

The **BeginGroup** content height is not fixed; inside this, there are many other elements. I need to add a rounded corner background for the group. I have tried to use the following code: After loading the content, I get the start Y and end Y, and then I try to create the drawlist. However, that drawlist appears in front of the content, whereas I want it to be set as the background.

```
ImVec2 GroupStartPos;

ImGui::BeginGroup();
GroupStartPos = ImGui::GetCursorScreenPos();

// Here you can add content to the group

// Calculate PanelHeight based on the content within the group
PanelHeight = ImGui::GetCursorPosY() - GroupStartPos.y;

// Draw the rounded-corner background inside the group
ImGui::GetBackgroundDrawList()->AddRectFilled(
    GroupStartPos,
    ImVec2(
        GroupStartPos.x + ThisChildSize.x,
        GroupStartPos.y + PanelHeight
    ),
    IM_COL32(255, 255, 255, 255),
    5.0f,
    ImDrawFlags_RoundCornersAll
);

ImGui::EndGroup();
```